# Assigning Private IP without dhclient

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, ip, dhclient

I am making custom python tkinter wifi application for ubuntu 18.04. I am using dhclient to assign IP once Wpa_supplicant has established connection.

Sometimes, dhclient is taking time to assign private IP like 192.168.0.x. My query is can I assign private IP via command line manually and start internet?

Note: I dont want to use Network Manager and switching to netplan would be a big challenge.

Comment: Is this a Desktop or Server installation? Are you asking how to assign a static IP to your computer? If Desktop, any reason to use CLI vs the normal NM GUI? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: @heynnema i am using dhclient to assign ip and connect to internet. Can i assign IP and connect to internet without use of dhclient?

Comment: Since you didn't answer any of my questions, I'm left to guessing what you're trying to do. But check `man interfaces`.

Comment: @heynnema sorry but i dont use netplan and further i uses interfaces file when i need to assign static ip to LAN. For wifi i use wpa_supplicant and then dhclient to assign ip.